# function get_html( $elements ) wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In the comment-form.php (I'm using a plugin) I have this:

```
function get_html( $elements ){     
  echo '<div class="wpad_section_html">';

  if( !empty($elements['help_text']) ){     
     echo $elements['help_text'];     
  } 
  echo '</div>';    
}
```

When from wordpress panel of this plugin I Insert that you can see in the image
"hello world" appears while shortcode doesn't appear.
What is the error?
Can someone help me?
**Thanks a lot** 
[image of html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftxDP.png)
Ps anothershortcodewithid is a name of shortcode
 [this is the image of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc6WW.png)

Comment: what type of plugin are you using

Comment: where you inserted this code in text or visual in admin panel